# How to return one whole code block in javascript

Tags: javascript, return, return-value, codeblocks

I'm trying to make a BMI calculator.

If you give a weight that is a string, negative number, or so forth it should write back (type in validate weight etc.) in console. But the thing is, I don't know how to return just the conditions for typing in weight and height, so if I type in wrong values for both it doesn't write back in console your BMI etc. But also, if I type, for example, good values for weight and height it actually returns BMI.

Here's the code

```js
let weight = 70
let height = 1.85

if (typeof weight !== 'number' || weight < 0) {
  console.log("Type in validate weight ")
}

if (typeof height !== 'number' || height < 0) {
  console.log("Type in validate height ")
}

function square(height) {
  return (height * height);
}

var result = BMI(height,
  weight);

function BMI(height, weight) {
  return (weight /
    square(height))
}

console.log(result);

if (result < 18.5) {
  console.log("Your BMI is too low ")
} else if (result < 25) {
  console.log("Your BMI is correct ")
} else if (result < 30) {
  console.log("Your BMI is a little too high ")
} else if (result >= 30) {
  console.log("Your BMI is too high ")
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You might revise your post and edit the snippet I created to add HTML so this thing actually functions. That would make debugging easier.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by "*"Type in*". The code you posted only contains some constant numbers declared right in the code. Where are you getting your input from, and how is this code executed? Is it part of a function that is called somewhere? A script loaded into a html page? A nodejs cli application?

Answer (score 0):

Do your validation all in one step, a function is a good way to achieve that, cand call it from your calculation

```js
function validateInputs(weight,height){
   let isValid = true;
   if (typeof weight !== 'number' || weight < 0) {
    console.log("Type in validate weight ")
    isValid = false;
  }

  if (typeof height !== 'number' || height < 0) {
    console.log("Type in validate height ")
    isValid = false;
  }
   
  return isValid;
}

function executeCalculator(weight,height){
  if(!validateInputs(weight,height))
    return;
    
  var result = weight / (height*height)
   
  console.log(result);

  if (result < 18.5) {
    console.log("Your BMI is too low ")
  } else if (result < 25) {
    console.log("Your BMI is correct ")
  } else if (result < 30) {
    console.log("Your BMI is a little too high ")
  } else if (result >= 30) {
    console.log("Your BMI is too high ")
  }
}


executeCalculator("",""); // Invalid
console.log("---")
executeCalculator("70",1.85);// Invalid
console.log("---")
executeCalculator(70,1.85);// Valid
```